# How to access PA flows shared to a group shared email account

Tags: outlook, powerapps, power-automate, microsoft365, power-automate-desktop

A Power Automate user has shared the ownership of their flows to a shared email account that the whole team has access to. However, when the team attempts to view the flows from the link in the email, Power Automate states that they do not have access to the flow, despite being a member of the shared email account. Will the other user need to share ownership with each individual instead?

Answer (score 0):

a shared email account would not give access, however, an O365 group would give members of that group shared access.